# Determine the fx:id of a pressed button

Tags: java, button, javafx

I am trying to set up a method used by three different buttons. I want to load one of three different views depending on which of them is pressed. To do so, I thought about passing as an argument the button itself. But I was unable, due to javaFX not recognising the method with the new argument.

How can I get the `fx:id` of the caller button so I can make the distinction between each of them? Here's what I got this far. I just need to initialize `pressed` variable so it will do its thing.

```
if (pressed == edgeModify){
    loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/digitalia/view/edgeView.fxml"));
} else if (pressed == sectionModify){
    loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/digitalia/view/sectionView.fxml"));
} else {
    loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/digitalia/view/LayerView.fxml"));
}
```

Comment: If you want to do different things with different button action, why don't you use different button actions for each button press?

Comment: I just thought since it might do the exact same thing apart from using a different URL I could implement it this way. It might be easier to just do each one separately though.

Comment: @A.Gimeno In this case your different handlers could simply be one-line methods, all invoking a common method but passing a different URL as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the id of the button as below:

```
Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
String id = btn.getId();
```

An easier approach would just be to use different handlers for the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different handler for each button. It looks like this would be as simple as:

```
@FXML
private void loadEdgeView(ActionEvent event) {
    load("edgeView");
}

@FXML
private void loadSectionView(ActionEvent event) {
    load("sectionView");
}

@FXML
private void loadLayerView(ActionEvent event) {
    load("layerView");
}

private void load(String view) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("/digitalia/view/" + view + ".fxml");
    // ...
}
```

---

If you *really* want to do this with a single method, you could leverage the [`userData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getUserData--) of the button; i.e.:

```xml
<Button text="Load Edge View" onAction="#loadView" userData="edgeView" />
<Button text="Load Section View" onAction="#loadView" userData="sectionView" />
<Button text="Load Layer View" onAction="#loadView" userData="layerView" />
```

and then in the controller:

```
@FXML
private void loadView(ActionEvent event) {
    Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
    String view = (String) node.getUserData();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("/digitalia/view/" + view + ".fxml");
    // ...
}
```

I think using separate handlers is more maintainable, for a small price in verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the source of the event object like this:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {if (e.getSource() == button) System.out.println("button was pressed.");});
```

In your above example you only have to exchange `pressed` with `e.getSource()`.

Answer (score -2):

```java
@FXML void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Expression e = new Expression("");

        String eventString = event.toString();
        System.out.println(eventString);
        String[] cutAtId = eventString.split("id=");
        cutAtId = cutAtId[1].split(", ");
        eventString = cutAtId[0];
        System.out.println("eventString ===>>>" + eventString + "<<<<====");
}
```

Comment: While this might work, it is just not as good a solution as [`((Node) event.getSource()).getId()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47924430/1155209).  Also, in general it is usually better to add some explanatory text in addition to code, rather than a code only answer.